# Return data from json and AJAX

Tags: javascript, json

I would like display all Jobs with XMLHttpRequest from json data, but i can not display my data. This my function :

```
function getJobs () {
  let httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  httpRequest.open('GET', 'http://codepen.io/jobs.json', true);
  httpRequest.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (httpRequest.readyState == 4) {
      let data = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
      Object.keys(data).forEach( (key) => {
        console.log(key[0].company_name); // undefine
      });
    }
  };
  httpRequest.send();
}

getJobs();
```

Can you help me about my forEach ? The json is object of array, with some object ^^

Thank you !

Comment: Each json object can be created individuelly. So hhat does run into an individuell solution.

Comment: I've test with `      Object.keys(data).map( (key) => {
        console.log(data[key][0]['title']);
      });` but with this solution, i can't display each Jobs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
function getJobs () {
  let httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  httpRequest.open('GET', 'http://codepen.io/jobs.json', true);
  httpRequest.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (httpRequest.readyState == 4) {
      let data = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
      data.jobs.forEach(function(key, value) {
         console.log(key.company_name);
      });
    }
  };
 httpRequest.send();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `key` variable holds the **name of the property** (i.e. the key), it doesn't hold the **value** of the property.

```
var value = data[key];
console.log(value[0].company_name);
```

Comment: Hi, this solution don't list all jobs in the array 'jobs'

Comment: @StéphaneR. — Well, no. You've looping over the properties of the object (it has one property "jobs"). If you want to loop over the array then you have to loop over the array instead.

Comment: So i need change to `Object.keys(data.jobs).forEach` ?

Comment: As an array you should be using `Array.prototype.forEach` instead. And you'll need to adjust how you drill down inside the result.